# Laravel Media - insert watermark (Quick Admin Panel)

Tags: php, laravel, media, watermark

I'm using Quick Admin panel for my project and now I need to insert watermark on every image.
This is my `store function` in my contoller:

```
if ($request->input('thumbnail', false)) {
   $automobil->addMedia(storage_path('tmp/uploads/' . $request->input('thumbnail')))->toMediaCollection('thumbnail');
}

foreach ($request->input('fotografije', []) as $file) {
   $automobil->addMedia(storage_path('tmp/uploads/' . $file))->toMediaCollection('fotografije');
}
```

How can I insert watermark in this code? I tried like:

```
$file->insert(public_path('images/watermark/watermark.png'), 'bottom-right', 10, 10);
```

but it's not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Milos you can use this additional package :
[Intervention image](http://image.intervention.io/) and add a watermark using it.